# Selecting Members Based on Chosen Service(s) Updates

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So basically there are four services offered by a resort:

```
services (Table with all resort services)
ser_id    ser_name
   1      Breakfast
   2      Dinner
   3      Towels
   4      Taxi
```

Members can select which services they would like when they book with the resort. There are three options with the corresponding member cases they apply to in the chosen_services table:

1. Choose individual services [member 6 case]
2. Choose all services at once [member 7 case]
3. Choose all services at once, then unchoose individual services [member 5 case]

To make things clearer, here is what the chosen_services table looks like:

```
chosen_services (Table with all member chosen resort services)
resort_id    mem_id    ser_id    chosen_type
    2           5         0          all
    2           5         1       cancelled
    2           5         2       cancelled
    2           6         4         chosen
    2           7         0          all
```

If there is a change in price for any of the services, we need to pull out the members who chose that service and email them with the change.

I've been stuck on this one for hours, how can we get this thing to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised based on your comment below:

I would probably actually consider adding the concept of service packages so you might introduce two new tables (packages and packages_to_services)

The tables might have following fields

```
packages
--------

pack_id    pack_name
    1      Breakfast Package
    2      Dinner Package
    3      Towels Package
    4      Taxi Package
    5      All Services Package

packages_to_services
--------------------

pack_id     ser_id
   1           1
   2           2
   3           3
   4           4
   5           1
   5           2
   5           3
   5           4
```

You would than change your `chosen_services` table to a `chosen_packages` table like this

```
resort_id    mem_id    pack_id    cancelled
    2           5         5          1
    2           5         3          0
    2           5         4          0
    2           6         4          0
    2           7         5          0
```

You would query for all for your information like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.mem_id 
FROM chosen_packages AS cp
INNER JOIN packages_to_services AS pts
  ON cp.pack_id = pts.pack_id
WHERE cp.resort_id = 2
AND pts.ser_id = 2
AND cp.canceled = 0
```

Note here that your application would need to have logic to understand that when member 5 deselected service 1 and 2, that he, in essence, cancelled package 5 and added packages 3 and 4.

Also if you need to add or remove a service from a package, it is simply a record insert/delete on the `packages_to_services` table, no need to update any other tables, as all users signed up for that package would automatically pick up the service change.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the quick response. The only issue I have is, if a new service is added for a resort, and 'all' is the chosen type for a member, they should automatically get it. so 'all' = (current+future) services. What do you think regarding the future part? (I am leaning more towards your first solution but need to know how the futures part will work)

Comment: @Maverick OK so it seems that you have to concept of service packages.  In that case I would create another additional table entirely which matches individual services to packages (which could include 1 or more services).  You would need to have logic at you application level to know how to break apart service packages for cases where one selects all and then cancels individual packages.

Comment: @Maverick See updated answer for more suggestions on working with package concept

Comment: The packages change just confused me. Let me take a few minutes to try and understand it.